# Re-validate all constraints

Tags: postgresql

On a server with ~200 databases, I experience several violated constraints when trying to migrate from Pg11 to Pg13 :

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "codesoeuvres_unicity1_other"
ERROR:  new row for relation "lienssupportscategories" violates check constraint "idcategoriesupport_notnull"
```

I don't know where or when these integrity problems came from. I have never disabled triggers so I am suspecting some data corruption (on indexes maybe?) These errors are not critical *per-se* but I would like to:

1. run a deep check on all databases to detect any inconsistency (maybe run this test once in a while)
2. delete/correct those invalid data

On [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989827/why-doesnt-validate-constraint-find-this-foreign-key-violation) @laurenz-albe suggested an **unsupported** option to de-validate a constraint and I'm considering writing a script to:

- (a) Invalidate each constraint with `UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_constraint SET convalidated = FALSE WHERE conname = yyy;`
- (b) re-validate it with `ALTER TABLE xxx VALIDATE CONSTRAINT yyy`

But I wonder:

1. Why is this not recommended? Is it (only) because someone might insert invalid data in the meantime between (a) and (b)? In that case, doing this inside a transaction seems safe.
2. Is there a better (at least **supported**) solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: Hmm, this sounds as if you are hit by https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, one of the options I considered (when I said "on indexes maybe?") which is reassuring (I prefer this to real data corruption).

Answer (score 0):

> run a deep check on all databases to detect any inconsistency (maybe run this test once in a while)

One way to run such a check is to make a snapshot backup (pg_dumpall) and then try to restore it.

> delete/correct those invalid data

this may be a slow preocess.